# Use Icon via CSS Class in jQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

i want to use a icon in jQuery Mobile on a span element...and i want to support retina display too. So how can i use a icon without giving my span a fix width?
Should i use Media Queries and try to get it working that way or is there any "offical way" to do it?

Regards
Nils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my procedure for making custom icons in jQM.

You need 2x png's one that is 18x18 and another that is 36x36

In your css:

```
//non-retina
.ui-icon-amazing {
    background-image: url("custom.png");
}

//retina
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .ui-icon-amazing {
        background-image: url("custom-hd.png");
        background-size: 18px 18px;
    }
}
```

To use your new icon, which you have called 'amazing' simply use the appropriate data-icon= attribute

```
data-icon="amazing"
```

and the icon will get applied.

You get bonus points for base64 encoding your png directly into your stylesheet.

Comment: this is not exactly what i am looking for. i want to use my icon on a plain old span tag, and data-icon attribute doesn't apply to span tags. at least not for me.

Comment: Here's a very dodgy example, it doesn't use the data-icon attribute but is a clone of what gets generated out of the data-icon code
http://jsfiddle.net/zbnqW/

Comment: thanks...i tried ui-btn-icon all the time, but it's just the same like jQuery UI. :D